# Generate a JSON instead of an image for the legend with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm not clear on how I can pass the **params** to [getLegendUrl](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileWMS-TileWMS.html#getLegendUrl). My aim is to obtain the JSON and for this scope I use the code below:

```
  var graphicUrl = wmsSource.getLegendUrl(
    resolution,
    'params': 'application/json',
  );
  console.log(graphicUrl);
```

In the console I see only the error below concerned to `'params': 'application/json',`:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: replace `'params': 'application/json'` with `{'FORMAT': 'application/json'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters should be an object, it should look like something like this :

```
var graphicUrl = wmsSource.getLegendUrl( resolution,
     {'REQUEST': '...',
      'LAYER': '...'
     }
);
```

The exact syntax of the parameters depends on your WMS server. For instance :

- MapServer : https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html
- GeoServer : https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html
- etc.